# Problems obfuscating with ProGuard an uberjar

Tags: java, proguard, maven-shade-plugin, uberjar

I have built a fairly big framework around third party libraries like TestNG, Selenium and so on.
As a requirement I'm required to obfuscate the code before distributing it.
To distribute the code, I have to create a single jar with all it's dependencies, which I did without problems with maven-shade.
The problem begins when trying to do some light obfuscation, using ProGuard, on it which I have not obfuscating the jar without the dependencies (omiting the shade stage).

I'm using the following settings in the POM.

**Shade stage**

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
            <transformerimplementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <mainClass>com.mycompany.main.Init</mainClass>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
        <filters>
          <filter>
            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </filter>
          <filter>
            <artifact>com.google.inject:guice</artifact>
            <includes>
              <include>**</include>
            </includes>
          </filter>
          <filter>
            <artifact>org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans</artifact>
            <includes>
              <include>**</include>
            </includes>
          </filter>
          <filter>
            <artifact>org.freemarker:freemarker</artifact>
            <includes>
              <include>**</include>
            </includes>
          </filter>
          <filter>
            <artifact>org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas</artifact>
            <includes>
              <include>**</include>
            </includes>
          </filter>
        </filters>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

**ProGuard stage**

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
  <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>proguard</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
    <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-uber.jar</outjar>
    <inFilter>!META-INF/versions/9/**.class</inFilter>
    <options>
      <option>-dontshrink</option>
      <option>-keep class !com.mycompany.**,!com.mycompany.** { *; }</option>
      <option>-keep class io.**</option>
      <option>-keep class org.**</option>
      <option>-keep class com.google.**</option>
      <option>-keep class freemarker.**</option>
      <option>-keep class javax.**</option>
      <option>-keep class com.sun.**</option>
      <option>-keep class com.jacob.**</option>
      <option>-keep class net.**</option>
      <option>-keep class com.google.**</option>
      <option>-ignorewarnings</option>
      <option>-keepdirectories</option>
      <option>-dontnote</option>
      <option>-dontwarn org.**</option>
      <option>-dontwarn io.**</option>
      <option>-dontwarn com.fasterxml.**</option>
      <option>-dontwarn okio.**</option>
      <option>-dontwarn okhttp3.**</option>
      <option>-dontwarn freemarker.**</option>
      <option>-dontwarn com.microsoft.**</option>
      <option>-libraryjars ${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</option>
      <option>-libraryjars ${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</option>
      <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
    </options>
    <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
      <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**The returned Stacktrace (Partial)**

```
[proguard] Warning: library class javax.mail.search.SearchException extends or implements program class javax.mail.MessagingException
[proguard] Warning: library class javax.mail.search.StringTerm extends or implements program class javax.mail.search.SearchTerm
[proguard] Warning: library class javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource extends or implements program class javax.activation.DataSource
[proguard] Warning: library class javax.mail.util.SharedFileInputStream extends or implements program class javax.mail.internet.SharedInputStream
[proguard] Warning: there were 369 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
[proguard]          You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
[proguard]          be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
[proguard]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
[proguard] Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
[proguard]   Class       = [freemarker/ext/jsp/TagTransformModel]
[proguard]   Method      = [getWriter(Ljava/io/Writer;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/io/Writer;]
[proguard]   Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [freemarker/ext/jsp/JspWriterAdapter] (with 1 known super classes) and [java/io/Writer] (with 2 known super classes))
[proguard] Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [freemarker/ext/jsp/JspWriterAdapter] (with 1 known super classes) and [java/io/Writer] (with 2 known super classes)
```

I'm guessing that the problem resides in ProGuard trying to get the dependencies from outside of the .jar instead of using only the ones inside but I have no clue, and coulnd't found one, if there is a way of making ProGuard use the libraries inside on the uberjar or, maybe, I'm wrong with the way I'm trying to obfuscate the jar

Comment: It feels to me like ProGuard is looking for the package `javax.mail` but can't find it.  Either put `javax.mail` on your class path or configure ProGuard to ignore that particular package.  I'm guessing though, caveat emptor.

Comment: It seems that the problem was in the shade stage. I specified org.freemarker when the correct one was freemarker. The build now complete correctly but the question is still there ¿Why is looking for library classes when the uberjar is supossed to have all of them? Another mistery to research for.

Comment: how about  obfuscate your code first then create uber jar, you gain nothing in obfuscating library jars

Comment: Yes, that was my first idea. But for I couldn't get that to work, it package everything like no ofuscation ever happened.
For the moment I'm ignoring the library jars using `-keep class !com.mycompany.**,!com.mycompany.** { *; }`. The stage duration is about 4 minutes and the result is a .jar of 30mb. I'm pretty sure that it can be optimized, probably like you suggest. I'll try to make time, try that again and coming back with the results. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue within a larger Maven project.
I fixed it by adding `javax.servlet.jsp` so that Proguard could then find the missing superclass(es).
Due to my project nature, I added that as Maven dependency in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

##### TL;DR (how I got there)

- Download the latest (at time of writing) `freemarker-2.3.31-sources.jar` from its [mvn repo](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.31/)
- explode its contents by `jar xf freemarker-2.3.31-sources.jar` console command
- explore resulted tree to `freemarker\ext\jsp\TagTransformModel.java`
- `getWriter(Writer out, Map args)` method uses `JspWriter`, coming from `import javax.servlet.jsp` at L31
- It is available from its [mvn repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api/2.3.3), hence the newly included dependency in the solution above.